# I want an invitation letter so I can go to Paris

Tags: visas, europe, france, nigerian-citizens, invitation-letters

I am a fashion designer from Nigeria. I really want to travel around the world, but I just don't know how to go about it. I really want to start by going to Disneyland.

Comment: You don't need an invitation letter as a tourist. You just need a good itinerary, coherent premise of application, strong ties to your home and means of support to get a visa.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to get an invitation letter to go to Disneyland. If you try to apply for a visa with one, you will probably be refused.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to go on a tourist visa, make sure you have enough money to fund the trip, arrange the accommodation, and return flights. You must have a stable source of income and you'll have to provide a copy of 3 or 6 months bank statement. Once you feel you are ready, just apply for a visa.

You do not require an invitation letter.

If you have a close relative who is eager to fund your trip, request them for an invitation letter. You can't go around the internet asking strangers for an invitation letter.

[Check This](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa) to know what documents you would require.

[Learn more](https://hotels.ng/guides/visa/france-visa-apply/) about French visa requirements for your country.

[VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/France/Nigeria/) is a third party that processes visa for several schengen countries including france.

Comment: A very nice answer!